# AX 2012 - Get Instance Name not Server Name in X++

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Is it possible to get the **Instance Name** instead of the **Server Name** in X++?

The attached image shows the field I am looking for:

[image: AX Config]

When I use `xSession.AOSName();` it returns the Server Name and when I use `sysServerSessions..Instance_Name;` an empty string is returned. The Instance_Name field only has "01" in the database so it would still be incorrect if it did return a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Instance name (optional)`, I believe is just the folder name and the service display name.  So when you create multiple instances, it creates a folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\[InstanceName]\`, and then an AOS service with that instance display name.

If you really want it, you could enumerate the folder and parse it using a regular expression or any number of other methods.  To enumerate the folder, create this **server** static method somewhere and call it:

```
static server FilenameOpen pathServer()
{
    return xInfo::directory(DirectoryType::Bin);
}
```

There is also a `ServerId`, which I don't think is the same as the `Instance Name`, but it's in the `SysServerConfig` table:

```
while select sysServerConfig
{
    info(strFmt("%1", sysServerConfig.ServerId));
}
```

And the `ServerId` is a derived value from the AOSId and name, etc. You can see how it's derived in this method:
`\Data Dictionary\Tables\SysServerConfig\Methods\delete`

Comment: Thank you Alex. Creating a Server Static method worked. I added some extra logic to retrieve the Instance Name.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the added logic to Alex's answer to get the Instance Name.

```
static server str getAOSInstanceName()
{
    str serverPath;
    str instanceName;

    int fullPathLen;
    int serverNameEnd;
    int instanceNameStart;

    //Get the full path of the AOS Server install.
    serverPath = xInfo::directory(DirectoryType::Bin);

    fullPathLen = strLen(serverPath);

    //Get the location of where the Instance Names Ends. "-5" represents "\bin\" in the full path.
    serverNameEnd = fullPathLen - 5;

    //Get the location where the Instance Name Starts - 1.
    instanceNameStart = strFind(serverPath, @"\", serverNameEnd, - fullPathLen);

    //Get the Instance Name.
    instanceName = subStr(serverPath, instanceNameStart + 1, serverNameEnd - serverNameStart);

    return instanceName;
}
```