# Getting axc file name and layer in X++

Tags: axapta, x++

I would like to know what is the syntax or code to identify the user's current use AOS name and current layer used?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See examples below:

```
xSession xSession;
xInfo    xInfo;
;

xSession = new xSession();
info(strFmt("Current AOS - %1", xSession.AOSName()));

info(strFmt("Current user - %1", curUserId()));

xInfo = new xInfo();
info(strFmt("Current layer - %1", xInfo.currentAOLayer()));
```

Comment: Hi Aliaksandr Maksimau, thankyou for the reply. The code works, however  xSession.AOSName does not provide the name that show on the right bottom corner in AX. It shows the AOS instance name instead

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744563/ax-2012-get-instance-name-not-server-name-in-x